# Run notepad++.exe from terminal

Tags: wine

How can I run notepad++.exe from terminal?

It's located under `/home/jon/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe` but when I execute

```
sudo /home/jon/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

it returns

```
sudo: /home/jon/.wine/drive_c/Program: command not found
```

Comment: I have a question. Why would you want to run notepad++ under wine? Ubuntu has a large selection of excellent text editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file you are trying to create or edit does not require root privilege, run this:

```
wine /home/jon/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

If it does require root permission at all, install the notepad++ with your root account after having been logged in as root (e.g. by executing `sudo -s -H`), log out, and run:

```
sudo wine /home/root/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

But usually, as has been pointed out, running wine applications as root is not recommended since
wine apps rely on wine and the source code of wine apps may or may not be reviewed, meaning
there is an increased amount of risk involved in doing so.

Comment: You can just use "wine /home/jon/...". sudo can be skipped as root privileges are normally not required for running wine apps.

Comment: It depends. Perhaps the questioner wants to create and/or edit a file in the editor where root permission is needed.

Comment: Thans. I can run it but if I omit `sudo`! I want to edit files but with sudo it says `wine: /home/jon/.wine is not owned by you` :( what should I do now? I am in full control of the computer and I have no problems running other stuff.

Comment: @Jon Do this: `$ sudo -s -H` and then install notepad++ with the root account. You only installed notepad++ for user `jon` but not for `root`.

Comment: @Gödel I uninstalled notepad++ and installed it again as root, it didn't work. I did the same thing for wine and installed it as root, but again... `jon@jon-desktop:~$ sudo wine "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"` says `wine: /home/jon/.wine is not owned by you` but this works fine `root@jon-desktop:/home/jon# wine "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"`

Comment: @Gödel I think that he created `.wine` dir with root privileges and now he cannot run wine. I would `chown` the dir to the correct user or delete and recreate it. [Running Wine as root is not recommended](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-96bebfa287b4288974de0df23351f278b0d41014)

Comment: How about running `$ sudo -s -H` and then `# wine /home/root/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe`? If you correctly installed notepad++ as root, it should execute fine.

Comment: @neon you were right on track. I recursively changed the owner of `.wine` to `root`! I know this is risky, but this will do the job for now, will fix it after my job is done.

Answer (score 1):

The space in the filename/path may be the main issue.

```
sudo /home/jon/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

should be:

```
sudo wine "/home/jon/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

and I do believe you must tell wine what exe to run.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a generic ones:
(Just copy paste on Terminal, & press ENTER key)

For Ubuntu x64 OS:

```
wine /home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

For Ubuntu x86 OS:

```
wine /home/$USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

If you dont know if your ubuntu is x86 or not, then type both above, one after the other, one will work.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Now that a snap has been created for notepad++, the cli command is just `notepad-plus-plus` (if you have the snap downloaded). That should open the app if not already open. If it's already open, you can still specify a file after the command and it will open that file in the already-open instance of notepad++.